# UnicodeEncodeError при запуске веб сервера Django?

Tags: python, django

Добрый день, уважаемые форумчане.
Начинаю изучать Джанго, создаю тестовый проект. Запускаю сервер, и тут ошибка.
Гуглил, пробовал варианты. Не получалось. Помогите, подскажите пожалуйста.
Изменение русского названия папки пользователя и имени пользователя на Латиницу, не помогло!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите скриншот или скопируйте вывод при запуске из каталога, путь к которому не содержит кириллических символов. Данная трассировка ругается именно на кириллическое имя каталога.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Вот, но ошибка как я понимаю идентична предыдущей. То есть ничего не поменялось. http://s008.radikal.ru/i306/1603/15/1ad4989a8650.png

Comment: Скриншот обрезан, я не вижу всю трассировку.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Прошу прощения. Вот: http://s018.radikal.ru/i528/1603/5e/783395894165.png . Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А вы виртуальное окружение пересоздавали после смены имени каталога?

Comment: Ммм, запускал только! Сейчас попробую!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Огромное спасибо! Реально помогло. Извиняюсь что я такой тупой)))! Благодарю еще раз!